# HTML Number Display Changes Font Size With JS Button Increment

Tags: javascript, html

So in short, I have been making a clicker game as a fun side project while learning to program. However I have one issue that has come up that for the life of me I can't seem to find an answer for.

The Problem:
In all clicker games, you generally have some sort of thing you are trying to collect. Cookie Clicker lets you click on a giant cookie image, which increases the amount of cookies you have.

I have all of the code in place for incrementing the number, however my problem lies in the fact that when you click to start collecting, the number that displays how much you have, changes it's font size to a smaller font, which looks tacky and unprofessional. I have images to show the before and after.

[Before Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwnZ1.png)
[After Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL4Gv.png)

As you can see in the second photo, the number font size has changed. Here is the code for displaying the integer:

```html
<p><img src = "http://www.zeldauniverse.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/GreenRupee.jpg" alt = "Rupee Image" style = width:50px;height:70px;><font size = "25" color = "#ffffff"> x: </font><a id="clicks"><font size="25">0</font></a></p>
```

And here is the snippet of code that I use for the button increment:

```html
function onClick() {
                        clicks += 1;
                        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
                        };
```

I can't seem to figure out why that would make the font size change, my only thought is maybe because I am using HTML to display the number and JS to change it, and thought maybe of using JS to display the number, but I have no idea how I would do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Don't ever use `<font>`.*  It's been deprecated for almost 20 years now (and you're removing it with JS when you update the number.) Use CSS to style the #clicks element.

Comment: More than deprecated, it's obsolete and been removed from [HTML](http://w3c.github.io/html/), though browsers likely support it for backwards compatibility.